# "Continuity" of the inverse image of a convex function

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Consider a (continuous) convex function $f$ defined on a compact subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and consider the sets
$$
S_t := \{x \in S \,:\, f(x) \leq t\}
$$
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

The claim is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $t$,
there exist $\delta > 0$ such that $d(S_t, S_{t'}) < \varepsilon$
as long as $|t' - t| < \delta$,
where $d(A, B)$ is the Hausdorff distance of two subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This claim should be true since I see people used it as for granted like in Witsenhausen's paper "Entropy Inequalities for Discrete Channels", in the proof of Lemma 1. It looks intuitive enough, too. But I can't figure out a proof myself or find any proof in textbooks I have for now.

Can anyone so kindly provide a proof source? It looks true even if $S$ is not compact...

Comment: In the non-compact case, it is no longer true: $S = \mathbb R$ and $f(x) = \exp(x)$.

Comment: @gerw: In that case is $S_t = (-\infty, \ln(t)]$ and the Hausdorff distance between $S_a$ and $S_b$ for $a < b$ is $\ln(b)-\ln(a)$, unless I am mistaken.